# react webpack file-loader - variable in required url

Tags: reactjs, webpack, loader

I'm using webpack and the file-loader plugin.
I wanna set an background-image in an react component, done like this:

```js
let bgImageUrl = require(`../../images/image.jpg`);
let bgStyle = {backgroundImage: 'url(' + bgImageUrl + ')'};

<div className="calender__item__link" style={bgStyle} ></div>
```

This works fine. 
But when I replace bgImageUrl with a variable like this:

```js
let bgImageUrl = require(`../../images/${event.image}`);
```

it's not working anymore: "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './' at..."

Any ideas? Do I have to use the url-loader because I'm using 'url()'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error:
the variable ${event.image} was loaded via JSON. in a few cases, it has a string, in other it was empty. the empty ones are throwing an error.